# What is the workflow of a docker image building?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-build, docker-daemon

I know to use the "docker build" to build an image from Dockerfile and it would package a tar to Docker daemon.

How does it work on Docker daemon when building the image? Is it create a temporary container?

Comment: Hi Tone! Please consider following this site https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/124022/docker-container if you have question about Docker containers

Answer (score 0):

A Docker image is roughly equivalent to a "**snapshot**" in other virtual machine environments. It is a record of a Docker virtual machine, or Docker container, at a point in time. Think of a Docker image as a digital picture. A Docker container can be seen as a printout of that picture. Docker images have the special characteristic of being immutable. They can't be modified, but they can be duplicated and shared or deleted. The immutability is useful when testing new software or configurations because no matter what happens, the image will still be there, as usable as ever.